# Rounding edges of a non uniform mesh

Tags: mesh

Given this hinge: [image: hinge]

I would like to round the 2 edges closes to the opening, without rounding the inset edge.

The aim is to model a wooden hinge such as this:

[image: wooden hinge].

I have looked at beveling, but it does not have the desired effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think beveling is a good option. Select the edges as pictured below, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and drag the cursor in opposite direction to the edges' location. Use <kbd>Mouse Scroll</kbd> to add some divisions. Finally change the rest of the mesh topology to easily add a *Subsurf* and *edge creases*.
[image]

Here's the final result with a changed topology.
[image]

And here's the .blend with improved topology: [image]